# Inserting Microdata into Jekyll output?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, microdata, jekyll-extensions

I've got a recipe site I'm powering with Jekyll, and now I want to add Microdata (`itemscope`, `itemprop`, etc.) into the output static page. I've got a couple lists (ingredients, directions, etc.) and I'm not sure how to have Jekyll render these with the added Microdata tacked on.

I assume I need a Convertor or Filter or some other thing, but I've got next to no experience with Jekyll. Anyone done something similar before?

Comment: Here's the markdown I've written, the current output, and the desired output: http://pastebin.com/YQ77C970

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way in [kramdown documentation](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html)

- {: itemprop="ingredient"} 2 tablespoons butter
- {: itemprop="ingredient"} 1 cup diced onion
- {: itemprop="ingredient"} 1 cup shredded carrot

But what if :

- you put your ingredients in the front matter

**my_recipe.md**

```
---
layout: page
title: My nice recipe
ingredients:
    - 2 tablespoons butter
    - 1 cup diced onion
    - 1 cup shredded carrot
---

{% include recipe_head.html %}

###How to do it

...
```

- make a template

**_includes/recipe_head.html

```
<h3>{{ page.title }}</h3>
<h4>Ingredients</h4>
<ul>
    {% for ingredient in page.ingredients %}
    <li itemprop="ingredient">{{ ingredient }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This will be far more maintainable.